# ¿Cómo transfiero ethers de un msg.sender a una dirección diferente?

Tags: blockchain, solidity

Estoy programando en Solidity "pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.7.0;" por primera vez y no entiendo como se podrían transferir una cantidad determinada de ethers de un msg.sender a una dirección diferente.

```
function comprarTokens(uint256 cantidad) public payable {
    require(cantidad > 0, "La cantidad solicitada no puede ser menor a 0");
    //Mirar que el cliente tenga los ethers suficientes
    require(msg.sender.balance > cantidad, "No tienes suficientes ethers");
    //Enviar ethers a la aseguradora
    address payable a = Cliente.direcAseguradora;
    a.transfer(cantidad);
    //Una vez reciba estos ethers, la aseguradora enviara los tokens corresponientes
}
```

La función de transferencia de ethers seria esta y lo que quiero es que coja los ethers que tengo disponibles en msg.sender y me los envie a la dirección "a", el problema es que así me coge la dirección del contrato en la que está definida la función "comprarTokens" y no la dirección msg.sender que yo quiero y que es la que tiene los ethers. He definido todas las direcciones que uso en la función como "payable". Estoy utilizando Remix.ide y la cuenta con los ethers seria esta:

[image: Entorno blockchain local]

Comment: Esto no es posible. Un contrato solo puede acceder a sus propios fondos, no puede gastar los fondos de otra cuenta. Dentro de la EVM que ejecuta los contratos de solidity no existe ningun opcode que permita a un contrato hacer transferencias de ether desde la cuenta de un tercero.

Answer (score 0):

```
function comprarTokens(uint256 cantidad) public payable {
    require(cantidad > 0, "La cantidad solicitada no puede ser menor a 0");
    require(msg.sender.balance >= cantidad, "No tienes suficientes ethers");
    address public a = Cliente.direcAseguradora;
// Tiene que ser en Weis
    payable(a).transfer(cantidad);
}
```

Comment: Por favor para que tu respuesta sea entendida debes explicarla, el codigo solo no basta

Answer (score 0):

puedes probar con requerir que que el usuario envie cierta cantidad de ethers y luego ether ese ether a la dirección que quieres

```
  require(msg.value >= 0.01 * 10 **18, "Necesitas enviar al menos 0.01 ether");
  payable(a).call{value:msg.value}("");
```